# Accessing current user information for a netsuite html form using suitescript

Tags: netsuite

I've been trying to figure auto-complete some values from netsuite onto our custom html form.

After a bit of researching, I found this gem: nlapiGetContext (http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/APIs/Dynamic%20HTML/SuiteScriptAPI/MS_SuiteScriptAPI_WebWorks.1.1.html)

which should do exactly what it says,

However, when doing a console.log dump of nlapigetcontext()

the following information is displayed, not my current logged in user information

[image]

Here is my current test script:

```
if (window.addEventListener) { // Mozilla, Netscape, Firefox
    window.addEventListener('load', WindowLoad, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
    window.attachEvent('onload', WindowLoad);
}

function WindowLoad(event) {
   alert(nlapiGetContext().getCompany());
   console.log(nlapiGetContext());
}
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is this form located? Context will only work if you are logged into the system, so this won't apply for online customer forms, those are considered to be "outside the system".

You can write a Suitelet to retrieve data from an external form if you are only retrieving values.

I use this to get campaign information on an external landing page.

```
function getCamData(request, response){
if ( request.getMethod() == 'GET' ){
    response.setHeader('Custom-Header-CamID', 'CamID');
    var camid = request.getParameter('camid');
    var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('campaign', camid);
    var o = new Object();
        o.thisid = camid; 
        o.promocode = rec.getFieldValue('campaignid'); 
        o.phone = rec.getFieldValue('custevent_cam_1300num');
        o.family = rec.getFieldValue('family');
        var myString = JSON.stringify(o);       
        response.write (myString);
}}
```

You request something like this:

https://forms.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=188&deploy=1&compid=xxxxxx&h=fb8224b74b24907a79e6&camid=8020

And returns something like this:

{"thisid":"8020","promocode":"CAM999","phone":"1800 111 222","family":"12"}

Also you can do server-side posting from an external site to a NetSuite customer online form, it will capture and validate the data as far as it has the entry fields set in NS, this is a great way to avoid using those horrible iframes.

Comment: Ah, Thank you. I created a sublet on the server to grab information from netsuite then i just pass it as a json object and it works just as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Use these functions

```
nlapiGetContext().getName()
nlapiGetContext().getUser()
nlapiGetContext().getRole()
nlapiGetContext().getRoleId()
nlapiGetContext().getRoleCenter()
nlapiGetContext().getEmail()
nlapiGetContext().getContact()
nlapiGetContext().getCompany()
nlapiGetContext().getContact()

nlapiGetUser()
nlapiGetDepartment()
```

For details check http://suitecoder.appspot.com/static/api.html