# How to get profile details from Netsuite using RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite

I am accessing the Netsuite using RESTlet by Oauth token. I could get a contact, customer, and other details. Now I want to get profile [acccount holder] details like my first name, last name, mail id, role, and so on.

What is the record type should i use to get above mentioned details?

Or what alternate code should use to get the details?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on type of user, mostly you would need to query

> employee

, it has all the details. when querying/searching you may want to add filter that `['giveacess', 'is', 'T']` as you only want to query users with login access.

> Other types of users can be customers, partners and vendors

These users can have access to their portals, eg: customer has access to customer portal, vendor to vendor portal and partner to partner portal.

For details on fields available to query , I suggest you to check [record browser link](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_1/script/record/partner.html)

Comment: Thank for reply. But i got the same following error even added your code.  [code] => INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION
            [message] => For security reasons, only an administrator is allowed to edit an administrator record. I am on a role of Cusom accountant. i got an idea by these posts. 1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545193/how-to-get-currently-logged-in-employee-details-in-netsuite-using-suitescript-wh   2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595887/accessing-current-user-information-for-a-netsuite-html-form-using-suitescript

Comment: Please make sure search is public or accessible to your role